# Hibernate and Scala

Tags: java, hibernate, scala

I have been toying with Scala and I was wondering if anyone had had any experience with using hibernate and mysql as a persistent store for scala objects? Does it work out of the box or is there a lot to do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Most of the time, Scala + Hibernate works quite well, with minor bumps which could be overcome easily. For exmaple, when dealing with collections, Hibernate requires the use of java.util interfaces. But you could import scala.collection.jcl.Conversions._ if you want to tap on Scala's more powerful library.

You may want to check out [Frank Sommers](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=276&thread=222229)' post for more information.

Comment: _Note:_ In scala 2.8 `scala.collection.jcl.Conversions` was moved to  `scala.collection.JavaConversions`.  So you should use `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._` in scala 2.8+.  Docs: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConversions$.html.

Comment: Note that enumerations are kind of a pain with Scala and Hibernate, but they are possible to implement. Although surprisingly it's easier in Java.

Answer (score 18):

It is definitely not a lot of work. A simple hibernate + scala example can be defined in a few tens of lines. Scala and Java can be mixed up in the same project. In particular, the hibernate-scala combination makes possible to combine the JPA framework, and a very flexible orm layer with the elegance of immutable structures and functional programming as provided by scala.

The easiest way to experiment with hibernate and scala is by using an in-memory hsqldb database via hibernate/jpa. First off, let’s define the domain model. In this case, a scala class annotated according to hibernate style, about my buddies.

```
package nl.busa.jpa
import javax.persistence._

@Entity
@Table(name = "buddy")
class Buddy(first: String, last: String) {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Int = _

    var firstName: String = first
    var lastName: String  = last

    def this() = this (null, null)

    override def toString = id + " = " + firstName + " " + lastName
}
```

Note how the scala class, is much more compact than the java class, since we don’t need the typical getter/setter boilerplate code. Now let’s make sure, that the jpa modules and the database model is loaded. According to the hibernate specification, let’s add the well known hibernate configuration file: resources/META-INF/persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="nl.busa.jpa.HibernateJpaScalaTutorial">
        <description>
        Persistence unit for the JPA tutorial of the Hibernate Getting Started Guide
        </description>
        <class>nl.busa.jpa.HibernateJpaScalaTutorial</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:JpaScala"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

After defining the persistency configuration, let’s move on the main scala file:

```
package nl.busa.jpa

import javax.persistence.EntityManager
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
import javax.persistence.Persistence

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object HibernateJpaScalaTutorial      {

  var entityManagerFactory: EntityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "nl.busa.jpa.HibernateJpaScalaTutorial" )
  var entityManager: EntityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()

  def main( args : Array[String]) {

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin()
    entityManager.persist( new Buddy( "Natalino", "Busa" ) )
    entityManager.persist( new Buddy( "Angelina", "Jolie" ) )
    entityManager.persist( new Buddy( "Kate", "Moss" ) )
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit()

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    val allBuddies = entityManager.createQuery("From Buddy", classOf[Buddy]).getResultList.toList
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    allBuddies foreach println 

    entityManager.close();

  }
}
```

The code is quite straightforward. Once the JPA EntityManager is created via the factory, the data model is available for insertion, deletion, query, using the methods defined in the documentation of hibernate and jpa.

This example has been set up using sbt. After retrieving the necessary packages, and compiling the source, running the tutorial will produce the following log:

```
HibernateJpaScalaTutorial:-:1.0.0> run
[info] Running nl.busa.jpa.HibernateJpaScalaTutorial 
1 = Natalino Busa
2 = Angelina Jolie
3 = Kate Moss
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Dec 9, 2012 4:18:00 PM
```

Answer (score 8):

Scala Query is not Hibernate but may be interesting.

- http://github.com/szeiger/scala-query
- http://szeiger.de/blog/category/scala/scala-query/
- [www.cs.uwm.edu/~dspiewak/papers/scalaql.pdf](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/~dspiewak/papers/scalaql.pdf)

Comment: The second link is dead

Answer (score 3):

There are issues.  Because some features of JPA leverage nested annotations, e.g. collections, you're in trouble because Scala does not yet support nested annotations.  That'll go away when 2.8 comes out.

See [Wille Faler’s Blog](http://faler.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/scala-jpa-some-gotchas-to-be-aware-of/) for more on this topic plus other incompatibilities.

Answer (score 3):

Note that Scala 2.8, now in RC5 and expected to release shortly, supports nested annotations.  The release has many other cool features as well.

Answer (score 3):

I am using hibernate with Scala. The real problem that I had to solve was how to persist Enumerations in hibernate. I've put my working solution on github

[Scala-enumeration-hibernate](https://github.com/marekzebrowski/scala-enumeration-hibernate)

Basically one needs to define own UserType

```
abstract class EnumerationAbstractUserType(val et: Enumeration) extends UserType {
   ....
  override def nullSafeGet(resultSet: ResultSet, names: Array[String], session: SessionImplementor, owner: Object): Object = {
    val value = resultSet.getString(names(0))
    if (resultSet.wasNull()) null
    else et.withName(value)
  }

  override def nullSafeSet(statement: PreparedStatement, value: Object, index: Int, session: SessionImplementor): Unit = {
    if (value == null) {
      statement.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR)
    } else {
      val en = value.toString
      statement.setString(index, en)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have not used Hibernate with scala directly, but I am using JPA. Hibernate provides a JPA implementation, and the way you define JPA persistent classes or Hibernate ones is not much different, so I think using Hibernate without the JPA layer is possible

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Scala version of Play Framework](http://scala.playframework.org/) where there is full JPA adaptation for Scala.